# How do you sort paragraph tags, or TD tags (for example), alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Say there is a table; I want to get the values in the third column of that table and alphabetize them.  I couldn't figure out how to pull information from html tags and alphabetize the text within, because I think it was alphabetizing the elements (all of which were the same).

Anyway, here's an example of my problem.  As you can see, I can get an alphabetized list from using alert(), but not with document.write() or jQuery's append().  Also notice that I can write a specific element from the array.

Why is this, and how can I resolve this issue?

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/kd4R7/

Comment: would love to.  Give me something that can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use .toString like this:

```
$('.here').append(letters.toString());
```

in your code and it works. `letters` is an array and it needs to be converted to string before append can be done. Or in a better way, use `html` instead of `append` like this:

```
$('.here').html(letters.toString());
```

This will replace the contents of `.here` instead of appending.

Comment: Perfect.  I actually tried this, but it didn't work at the time.  I was trying so many combinations of things.  I adapted your answer by replacing those commas: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/kd4R7/1/

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you're asking for but for table sorting http://tablesorter.com/docs/ is really nice.

Comment: No.  That does look nice though.